# List sms on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

On windows phone 7 it was not possible to access sms data. Is it possible on Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Source: the official [WPDev Feedback Forum](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-access-api):

> **SMS Access API**:
>   Cliff Simpkins (Sr Product Manager, Windows Phone Developer) responded:
>   **There isn’t a new API in the WP8 Dev Platform**

Comment: Thanks. By the way is it possible to access emails data?

Comment: No, there is no Email Access API

Comment: I'm trying to build a global search (like iOS), but it's not possible. Every main search are not available :/ Sorry about too many questions, but what about searching all applications instaled on phone?

Comment: No, there is no way to get the list of installed apps. Windows Phone applications are sandboxed, which means they can't directly interact with user data or phone functionality. Basically every personnal information of the phone cannot be accessed, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

No.

At least it's not mentioned in new features available in Windows Phone 8.0 SDK.
Source

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[WindowsPhoneGeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/whats-new-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-for-developers)